# css: issue with :last-child selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
p:last-child
{
background:#ff0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Question:

If i change

```
p:last-child
    {
    background:#ff0000;
    }
```

to

```
:last-child
        {
        background:#ff0000;
        }
```

then the whole page became red. why? what is the difference between `p:last-child` and `:last-child`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p:last-child` will select a `p` element if it's a `last-child`, if you've any other element as your `last-child` it will fail

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XNdRm/)

In this case, you should use a more stricter pseudo like

```
p:last-of-type {
   background:#ff0000;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/XNdRm/1/)

The above will select `p` element, which is last regardless of any other element which can be `last-child` of the parent element.

---

Coming to this selector, `:last-child`, is not specific at all, you haven't specified `last-child` of what? So it will select any parent elements `last-child`

So

```
:last-child {
    background:#ff0000;
}
```

Will select `i` and `body` element but NOT `p` as it's not the `last-child` of `body`, same way if you use `:last-of-type` it will select

`i` `body` as well as `p` because now we are using `last-of-type` so it selects last element of each distinct element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XNdRm/3/)

---

You can use `firebug` to inspect each element and see how the elements pick up these properties.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `:last-child` selector selects all elements that are the last child of their parent.

Answer (score 0):

By default all elements selected it, the first one is to specify the p element. [Google Translation]

Answer (score 0):

`p:last-child` works by applying the CSS property to only the last child of a paragraph element.

`:last-child` works by applying the CSS property to the last child of the parent element. In this case, the last child would always be the `body`, since we always have one `body`, right? :)